# Sorting a vector of (double precision) reals and obtain their

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, permutation

In C++ would like to sort a lengthy (`2^20`) vector of reals, obviously `sort()` does the trick. Having used R before I was used to the nice `order()` function which yields the permutation that leads to the sorted vector.

Example:

```
x = {24, 55, 22, 1}
```

Then the permutation

```
perm = {3, 2, 0, 1}
```

Maps the original `x` to the sorted `x` in ascending order.

I can probably implement some bubble sort which does not only sort x but performs the same transpositions on the vector `{0,1,2,...}` and outputs both, but I believe someone must have thought about it and especially have done it efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Better than before approach without using helper vectors: ([source on ideone](http://www.ideone.com/wRHYv)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<class Vals>
void sortingPermutation(const Vals& values, std::vector<int>& v){
  int size = values.size(); 
  v.clear(); v.reserve(size);
  for(int i=0; i < size; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [&values](int a, int b) -> bool { 
    return values[a] < values[b];
  });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> values;
    values.push_back(24);
    values.push_back(55);
    values.push_back(22);
    values.push_back(1);

    std::vector<int> permutation;
    sortingPermutation(values, permutation);

    typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator I;
    for (I p = permutation.begin(); p != permutation.end(); ++p)
        std::cout << *p << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I am using lambda from C++0x, but it can be replaced with simple functor object:

```
template<class T>
struct CmpPairs{
  CmpPairs(const std::vector<T> &v): v_(v) {}
  std::vector<T> v_;
  bool operator()(int a, int b){ return v_[a] < v_[b]; }
};

template<class T>
CmpPairs<T> CreateCmpPairs(const std::vector<T> & v) { return CmpPairs<T>(v); }
//in sortingPermutation:
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), CreateCmpPairs(values));
```

Source of old solution with `std::map`: [ideone](http://www.ideone.com/k1Fxj)

Comment: The rule-of-thumb I've seen is that sorting a vector is more efficient than using a self-sorting container. Never tested it to see how true it is.

Comment: Even better one with use of C++0x (lambda could be replaced with functor): http://www.ideone.com/wRHYv I think much better than antonakos'es, because there are no helper objects just to sort.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the best way would be to create a vector of ints 0..N and then sort that array with a comparison function that compares the corresponding elements of the vector you're trying to find the sorted permutation of.  Something like:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T> class sorter {
    const std::vector<T> &values;
public:
    sorter(const std::vector<T> &v) : values(v) {}
    bool operator()(int a, int b) { return values[a] < values[b]; }
};

template<class T> std::vector<int> order(const std::vector<T> &values)
{
    std::vector<int> rv(values.size());
    int idx = 0;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = rv.begin(); i != rv.end(); i++)
        *i = idx++;
    std::sort(rv.begin(), rv.end(), sorter<T>(values));
    return rv;
}
```

This minimizes the allocation overhead, as we don't create any large temporary object that we sort and then extract the final permution -- the same vector that is being returned is the temp for sorting.

Comment: I like your approach, but it won't compile. You should correct it. Here a little corrected code, still won't compile, but I don't have time: http://www.ideone.com/hM8SC

Comment: @Pawel: Some versions of gcc are buggy and don't like local class declarations inside template functions that are then passed to other template functions, so I split it out to avoid that problem.

Comment: This code compiles successfully- although I note that the post was edited after your comment.

Comment: @DeadMG: The orignal code (after fixing the trivial typos -- missing `;`) will compile with gcc 4.5 -std=c++0x.  The modified code above will also compile with gcc 4.4

Comment: In C++0x you can use lambda function, instead of functor object (check my edited answer). The code is even shorter, and IMO cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::sort` to sort the list of pairs {(24, 0), (55, 2), (22, 0), (1, 1)}. It isn't particularly pretty, but I usually do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<double, int> Pair;

struct CmpPair
{
    bool operator()(const Pair& a, const Pair& b)
    { return a.first < b.first; }
};

void sortingPermutation(
    const std::vector<double>& values,
    std::vector<int>& permutation)
{
    std::vector<Pair> pairs;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)values.size(); i++)
        pairs.push_back(Pair(values[i], i));

    std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), CmpPair());

    typedef std::vector<Pair>::const_iterator I;
    for (I p = pairs.begin(); p != pairs.end(); ++p)
        permutation.push_back(p->second);
}
```

Here is the test:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> values;
    values.push_back(24);
    values.push_back(55);
    values.push_back(22);
    values.push_back(1);

    std::vector<int> permutation;
    sortingPermutation(values, permutation);

    typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator I;
    for (I p = permutation.begin(); p != permutation.end(); ++p)
        std::cout << *p << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Well done. Also, making this a template to be able to sort not only doubles will be great. And, of course, calling a `reserve` on a vector will save you lots of time by reducing a number of calls to `new/malloc`.